# How to optimally combine two collections in LINQ with several conditions for MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

As you know, on the Internet, examples are given for two collections, which are connected according to several conditions:

```
var query = from e1 in seq1
                   from e2 in seq2
                   where (e1.Key1 == e2.Key1)
                        && (e1.Key2 == e2.Key2)
                   select new {Data1 = e1.Data, Data2 = e2.Data};
```

However, when working with MS SQL Server, a similar LINQ construction will turn into a CROSS JOIN in T-SQL. You can easily see this if you convert the result to the ObjectQuery type, and then call the ToTraceString method:

```
string sql = (query as ObjectQuery) .ToTraceString ();
Console.WriteLine (sql);
```

Then, for the condition And, when connecting two collections, it is better to use a tuple in the internal connection instead of the Cartesian product from-from LINQ:

```
var query = from e1 in seq1
                 join e2 in seq2
                 on new {e1.Key1, e1.Key2} equals new {e2.Key1, e2.Key2}
                 select new {Data1 = e1.Data, Data2 = e2.Data};
```

However, how to do this for the condition OR:

```
var query = from e1 in seq1
                   from e2 in seq2
                   where (e1.Key1 == e2.Key1)
                           || (e1.Key2 == e2.Key2)
                   select new {Data1 = e1.Data, Data2 = e2.Data};
```

However, with an internal connection to the left of the equals keyword cannot be e2, but to the right is e1, then you can write as follows:

```
var query = (from e1 in seq1
                        join e2 in seq2
                        on e1.Key1 equals e2.Key1
                        select new {Data1 = e1.Data, Data2 = e2.Data}).Union (from e1 in seq1
                                      join e2 in seq2
                                      on e1.Key2 equals e2.Key2
                                      select new {Data1 = e1.Data, Data2 = e2.Data});
```

Yes, requests generally turn out to be nonequivalent, taking into account that full duplicates of rows can be returned. However, in real life, full duplicate lines are not needed and they are trying to get rid of them.
Is it possible to write the last query more optimally both in performance and in perception of the code?
Examples of bad solutions for LINQ queries to MS SQL Server:
http://qaru.site/questions/2444051/greater-than-with-multiple-conditions-in-linq-join
and
http://qaru.site/questions/231459/linq-left-join-on-multiple-or-conditions

Plans:

1) for CROSS JOIN, the average lead time is 195 seconds:
[image]

2) for INNER JOIN-UNION, on average, the execution time is less than 1 second:
[image]

**Amendment**. After all the tests, it turned out that AND gives INNER JOIN, and OR gives CROSS JOIN

Comment: There's no obvious reason why you shouldn't use the query that generates a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: The problem is when the tables are large

Comment: But CROSS JOIN isn't a problem _per se_.  SQL Server won't compute the entire Cartesian product before applying the filters.

Comment: Alas, as the measurements showed, the RAM for such requests is allocated such as if a Cartesian product occurs there before applying filters

Comment: SQL Server will allocate memory to store all the data you read from disk, up to its configured limit, or until the computer is low on physical memory.  And the query may be very expensive, but changing it from a CROSS JOIN to some other kind of join isn't really going to help.

Comment: You are mistaken because the query plans for CROSS JOIN and INNER JOIN are different. And I observed that INNER JOIN is better than CROSS JOIN both in terms of resource consumption and in terms of execution time.

Comment: Can you post the queries and query plans?

Comment: Of course. I will provide plans tomorrow. Thank

Comment: What is wrong with the `Union` answer?

Comment: 1. Please paste in the final SQL queries. 2. Please post the execution plans. A `cross join` with a limiting `where` clause should translate to the exact same execution plan as an `inner join` with the same limits in the `on` clause.

Comment: I simply clarified whether there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Today I will add plans later

Comment: Screenshots of plans for requests attached, look please

Comment: The cross join query should also contain conditions for key1 and key2 equality. Are you sure you are looking at the correct queries?

Comment: I have attached photos of the requests and their respective plans

Comment: I apologize, colleagues, in the condition I forgot to add to the CROSS JOIN condition for the connection from INNER JOIN. However, for the condition OR optimization is needed and described correctly

Comment: I would argue that some "optimization" _might_ be required at the SQL Server level, which is responsible for processing `JOIN` with `OR`-ed conditions slower then `UNION` over same `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: For the condition OR, I have so far received the best option as described in the last option in the question. But maybe there is a better in terms of code perception